# I can move back or forth in line only 1 character a time. How I can fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, typing-break

I have a new Dell laptop Precision something, and worked with a mouse. But my touch-pad made a lot of trouble with cursor jumping all over screen, and I managed to switch it off. Now I am back to stable typing, but have a new trouble: when I type, I can go only one character a time  either back or forth or up or down (i. e. cannot scroll continuously when needed), which slows me down tremendously.  Just in case : I have Linux ubuntu 14.04 installed, and a more or less standard .vimrc. What is the treatment?
Thanks, Al

Comment: @drg  : to solve the touchpad problem I used two alternative commands: (1) 'xinput set-prop 16 "Device Enabled" 0' or (2) 'synclient TouchpadOff=1'.

Comment: @drg : Great; you gave me the right terminology! I went into "System setting" then into "Input devices", and in the section "Keyboard repeat" found three options : "turn on", "turn of" and "leave unchanged". For whatever reason it was on "turn of" , and to be on safe side I simply clicked on  "leave unchanged". It worked! (after login out and back).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to stay on protocol: following a very helpful question by drg,  I went into "System setting", then into "Input devices", and in the section "Keyboard repeat" found three options : "turn on", "turn of" and "leave unchanged". For whatever reason it was on "turn of" , and to be on a safe side I simply clicked on "leave unchanged". It worked. I still don't know how it got into the position "turn of", perhaps I did it somehow inadvertently myself; but at least I know the "name" of the problem for the future. (You have a dumb user here...)